# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect causing distortion

Tags: iphone, cgimage

I'm using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect to do a magnifying effect, and it works beautifully, except when I get close to the edges of my view.  In that case, clipping causes the image to be distorted.  Right now I grab a 72x72 chunk of the view, apply a round mask to it, and then draw the masked image, and a circle on top.

When the copied chunk is near the edge of the view, It winds up smaller than 72x72 because of clipping, and then when it's drawn in the magnifying glass it gets stretched out.

When the touch point is close to the left edge, for example, I would like to create an image where the left part is filled with a solid color, and the right half contains part of the view that's being magnified.  Then apply the mask to that image and add the overlay on top.

Here's what I'm doing now.  imageRef is the image being magnified, mask is a round mask, and overlay is a circle to mark the edges of the magnified region.

```
CGImageRef subImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - 36, touchPoint.y - 36, 72, 72));
CGImageRef xMaskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMask(subImage, mask);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, xform);

CGRect area = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - 84, -touchPoint.y, 170, 170);
CGRect area2 = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - 80, -touchPoint.y + 4, 160, 160);
CGContextDrawImage(context, area2, xMaskedImage);
CGContextDrawImage(context, area, overlay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using CGBitmapContextCreate() to create a bitmap context.  Then I drew the captured area into a smaller area of this context, and created an image from it with CGBitmapContextCreateImage().  That was the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I also facing same issue, can you explain bit more detail this.